# How to receive webhooks from paypal donations? (and a few other misunderstandings)

Tags: paypal, webhooks, paypal-sandbox, paypal-webhooks

Good day, everyone. I'm a bit stumped on this subject. I have a bit of experience with PayPal developer apps when it comes to subscriptions but this issue with donations is stumping me.

I would like to receive webhooks when a donation is made. I have created a new app in paypal developer dashboard, assigned it the webhook URL (a web app running on Python Flask) and while I have been able to successfully send and receive mock sandbox webhooks from the developer sandbox dashboard for testing so I know everything is configured to work. I just can't figure out how to now establish the live environment donations handling.

I have a business and a developer PayPal account. Within my business account (which I assume is the one that does live donation transactions), I have created a donation button. Logic would dictate that within this donation button setup, there should be a select option to specify the app who's webhooks these donations need to be using. But there is no such thing and PayPal's developer forum is deserted.

The general question is:

How does one set up a donation button to receive webhooks to a certain app or is that not how this works? Because I can have multiple donation buttons for various purposes, campaigns and configurations and I don't need webhooks for all of them. If I am forced to receive all donations, at least I see that there's a donation button ID which I can use to filter out donations coming from other buttons. But I can't even do that if I am not receiving donation webhooks at all.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like for the time being to make this work I have to use Smart Buttons instead of donation buttons in Paypal. With smart buttons I can specify an app id I created in the developer dashboard and receive the webhooks this way.